# Appropriate way to set property for NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, ios

I want a mutable array and set it by a property,  which alternate is preferable and please explain  the reason. I have the 2 alternatives

```
 NSMutableArray *arrSubTitles_temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:    
 @"String 1",
 @"String 2",nil];
 self.arrSubTitles = arrSubTitles_temp;
 [arrSubTitles_temp release];
```

**OR**

```
 NSArray *arrSubTitles_temp = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:    
 @"String 1",
 @"String 2",nil];
 self.arrSubTitles = [arrSubTitles_temp mutableCopy];
 [arrSubTitles_temp release];
```

I guess the 1st one is better, as self.arrSubTitles property is retained in .h, so (in 2nd) mutableCopy method will provide the mutable array, but also the retain count will be 2 in this case.

Which method is preferable, should I use retain in .h while setting the property or just assign. Please suggest.

Many thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Use `retain` as your property attribute, unless you have a good reason not to (ex: `retain` would cause a retain cycle, it's a primitive, you need to guarantee the object is immutable, etc)
2. Use the first example you posted, since the second one would leak memory.

---

If you use `assign` as your property attribute, then the first option would probably crash:

1. Allocate an array (owned by you)
2. Assigned to a property (still owned by you)
3. Release (no owners, promptly deallocated)
4. Attempt to access property value: crash (because the pointer is stale)

The second one, however, would work:

1. Allocate an array (+1 owners)
2. Copy the array (original: +1 owners, copy: +1 owners)
3. Assign the copy into the property (both still have +1 owners)
4. Release the original array (it gets deallocated, the copy continues to exist)

Regardless, it is rather unconventional to have an `assign` property and then manage the retention of the value yourself.  It is extremely error-prone, and much simpler to declare the property as `retain` and let the generated setter take care of the `release`/`retain` dance for you.

Comment: Thanks. but can you explain me what will  happen in this case if I use assign, instead of retain in .h?

Comment: This answer just helped the whole of memory management fall into place for me. Thanks DD

Answer (score 3):

Either way is problematic because the caller must provide a mutable array. If the caller ever passes an immutable array (as anything that uses KVC to set the property would be able to do without a compiler warning), you will find yourself holding an immutable array in a mutable-array property, and will shortly thereafter try to mutate it, causing an exception.

What I do is hold a mutable array, which I create in `init` and release in `dealloc`, as the value of the property, declare the property as `@property(nonatomic, copy) NSArray *myArray`, and implement `setMyArray:` to send a `setArray:` message to my mutable array. At no point do I ever switch out the array; I exclusively and privately own the same mutable array for the entire lifetime of my object.

An equivalent implementation of `setMyArray:` would release the array and set the `myArray` variable to a `mutableCopy` of the input array. The only difference is that this would create and throw away more arrays over the duration of the process.

With either of these solutions, the caller does not need to worry about whether it passes a mutable or immutable array; the property will always do the right thing. And the caller would, as usual, not need to retain it on my behalf.

Note that a setter implementation generated by `@synthesize` will not do the right thing. It sends `copy` to the input array, which will return an immutable copy. This would be even worse, as then it would not work even if the caller does pass in a mutable array. You must implement a custom `setMyArray:` accessor to correctly handle both immutable and mutable arrays.

Comment: Thanks Peter, but here my property is not declared as immutable array, it is declared as NSMutableArray in .h; so I guess, there is no need to create my own getter/setter, as the caller will always be passing the Mutable array. I might be wrong, but this is what I think.Please suggest

Comment: The problem of letting the caller pass the mutable array and then just retaining it is that then you both hold the same mutable array. The caller can then mutate the array without your knowledge, adding objects that you don't know about and may not want, and removing objects you do know about/want. It is safer and simpler for your ownership of the mutable array to be exclusive and private. If you do make the property publicly mutable, it should be only through accessor methods: http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ModelObjects/Articles/moAccessorMethods.html

Comment: That's a really great way of handling NSMutableArray properties, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What about the setting it as autorelease
NSMutableArray *arrSubTitles_temp = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
 @"String 1",
 @"String 2",nil] autorelease];
 self.arrSubTitles = arrSubTitles_temp;
 [arrSubTitles_temp release];

Comment: I believe this is not a good idea, as we would be releasing the same  object (arrSubTitles_temp) twice, causing the over-released of this object. I might be wrong, but as per I know, this is not accurate